# Python Return text between two markers for a CSV file

Tags: python

File:
abcaddress\nCity\nCA\n92384
abcaddress\nCity\nTX\n75661
abcaddress\nCity\nNC\n28079
[877 rows x1 columns]

Please advise how I can return something like the following:
CA
TX
NC
...

I am thinking if there is a code that allows me to
find all the data between \n and \n
and if it is two characters, it will be returned

Many thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you open a file and read line by line you will, by definition (except for the first and last line) be acquiring data between two newline characters. Therefore, apart from the aforementioned caveat, you only need to check the length of each line

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use regex to find these. The findall will find all non-overlapping text that matches. The () in the second argument to findall specifies what to return. And the re.MULTILINE will allow the matches to happen accross lines.

```
import re

text="abcaddress\nCity\nCA\n92384 abcaddress\nCity\nTX\n75661 abcaddress\nCity\nNC\n28079"

matches = re.findall( '\n(..)\n', text, re.MULTILINE )

for match in matches:
    print (match)
```